# How to put link on each month in input( type month)

Tags: php, html

I am trying to do something in php when a month is selected in

```
<input type="month">
```

I managed to do it with select as following ->

```
<select name="forma" onchange="location = this.value;">
              <?php 
                 foreach($allusers as $usersx) { 
                 $idus = $usersx['id']; ?>
<option value="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?ufil=$idus" ?>"><?=$usersx['firstname']?> <?=$usersx['lastname']?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
</select>
```

My question is, is there any way to do the same thing with input month without actualy having to confirm it with some kind of button.

Comment: Did you try to move the `onchange` to that input and see? :D You will most likely want to create a PROPER javascript handler for that though. As inline `onchange` is so oldschool and limiting its not funny.

Answer (score 0):

Actualy figured it out, for anyone who need to use it here:

```html
 <input type="month" id="month" >
                            <script>
                                $(function() {
                                    // bind change event to select
                                    $('#month').on('change', function() {
                                        var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
                                        if (url) { // require a URL
                                            window.location = "filesall.php?date="+url; // redirect
                                        }
                                        return false;
                                    });
                                });

                            </script>
```